# How should I parse this JSON from the api using python? Python returns json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, http, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON from this api https://www.tiktok.com/api/user/detail/?aid=1988&app_name=tiktok_web&device_platform=web_pc&uniqueId=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfds, but when I do it returns as json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). My code is here

```
import json, requests 

url = requests.get("https://www.tiktok.com/api/user/detail/?aid=1988&app_name=tiktok_web&device_platform=web_pc&uniqueId=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfds")
text = url.text

data = json.loads(text)

print(data)
```

Comment: It looks like the response is empty.  try `print(text)`

Comment: Did you try to check the value of `text` *before` the `json.loads` call? What value did you get? Do you know what it should look like instead?

Answer (score 0):

Servers usually forbid automated requests, and the easiest check is to verify headers passed in the request. By default `requests` library uses `'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1'`, but if you change it to a browser-like useragent you'll get expected response:

```
In [10]: requests.get("https://www.tiktok.com/api/user/detail/?aid=1988&app_name=tiktok_web&device_platform=web_pc&uniqueId=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfds", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}).json()
    ...:

Out[10]:
{'statusCode': 10202,
 'userInfo': {'user': {'id': '',
   'uniqueId': '',
   'nickname': '',
   'avatarThumb': '',
   'avatarMedium': '',
   'avatarLarger': '',
   'signature': '',
   'relation': 0},
  'stats': {'followingCount': 0,
   'followerCount': 0,
   'heartCount': 0,
   'videoCount': 0,
   'diggCount': 0,
   'heart': 0}}}
```

Note, that you must follow API rules and recommendations, therefore I suggest you to try to find official guide how to use their API correctly (what headers to pass, what rate limits are, etc.)